# is it possible for a multi widget to use two different model fields

Tags: django, model, field, django-multiwidget

i have been really pulling my hair out to get this done. I have 2 integer fields in one of my models as follows:

```
#models.py

class TestModel(models.Model):
    """
    This is a test model.
    """

    max = models.IntegerField()
    min = models.IntegerField()
```

As the above two values are inter-related i wanted them to use a custom widget. Now here is the point, I want these fields to use a single custom widget (MultiWidget) but i also want to keep the values in separate columns in the database [Don't really want to parse stuff and moreover the search functionality will use the above fields separately so just want to store them separately].

A custom widget would only accept value from a single model field so i decided to create a custom form field to use in the ModelForm for the above model.

Now this is how my form looks.

```
class MinMaxField(forms.MultiValueField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        all_fields = ( 
            forms.CharField(),
            forms.CharField(),
            )   

        super(MinMaxField, self).__init__(all_fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, values):
        if values:
            return '|'.join(values)
        return ''

class TestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    minmax = MinMaxField(widget=widgets.MinMaxWidget(),
             required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.TestModel
        fields = ('min', 'max', 'minmax')
        widgets = {
            'min' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'max' : forms.HiddenInput(),
        }

    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'minmax_0' in self.data:
            newdata = self.data.copy()
            newdata['min'] = self.data['minmax_0']
            newdata['max'] = self.data['minmax_1']
            self.data = newdata
        super(TestModelForm, self).full_clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

The above form basically hides the model fields and shows only the `minmax` field that uses a custom widget as follows:

```
class MinMaxWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        mwidgets = (widgets.Select(attrs=attrs, choices=MIN),
                   widgets.Select(attrs=attrs, choices=MAX))
        super(MinMaxWidget, self).__init__(mwidgets, attrs)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        try:
            values = [widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)\ 
                      for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]

            value = [int(values[0]), int(values[1])]
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Value %s for %s did not validate. \
                              a list or a tuple expected' % (value, self.widget))
        return value

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                return value
            return [value[0], value[1]]
        return [None, None]

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        rendered_widgets.insert(0, '<span class="multi_selects">')
        rendered_widgets.insert(-1, '<label id="min">Min</label>')
        rendered_widgets.append('<label id="max">Max</label></span>')
        return u''.join(rendered_widgets)
```

Now at this point everything works fine, the values get saved separately into their respective fields. But the problem arises when i am trying to edit the form with an instance of a `TestModel` object. In the case of edit, when the form is rendered the actual values are stored in the hidden `min` and `max` input fields and the minmax field does not have a value. [ofcourse as it is a form field.]

What are the options i have to

1. Either pre-populate the value of the `minmax` form field from the `min` and `max` fields. [Note: Without Using Javascript or jQuery]
2. Or to create a MultiWidget that uses the values from two different model fields.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what version are you using ?

Comment: Did anyone find out a way to do this... same issue here...

Answer (score 1):

I've currently faced similiar problem and there is a way to use widget for two fields.
I'm using version 1.4 and haven't tried in any other.

In your view, you probably have something like this:

```
form = TestModelForm(instance=instance)
```

where `instance` is object from your database you want to edit.
Let's see what Django is doing when it creates your form

```
# django/forms/models.py

class BaseModelForm(BaseForm):
     def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                  initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=':',
                  empty_permitted=False, instance=None):
          ...
          if instance is None:
              ...
          else:
              self.instance = instance
              object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
          # if initial was provided, it should override the values from instance
          if initial is not None:
              object_data.update(initial)
          ...
          super(BaseModelForm, self).__init__(data, files, auto_id, prefix, 
                                              object_data, error_class, 
                                              label_suffix, empty_permitted)
```

then, when form is rendered, `BoundField` class uses this `object_data` to assign initial value to the widget.

Therefore all you need to do is provide `initial` in your form constructor.

```
class TestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            initial = dictionary with initial values
            initial.update(kwargs['initial'] or {})
        ...
        super(TestModelForm, self).__init__(initial=initial, *args, **kwargs)
```

Also remember to add your field to your forms `fields` list.

That way you don't have two unused hidden widgets, no need to use javascript and imo, code is more explanatory.